# Publishing A Facebook Messenger Bot through Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

One of my recent project needs to create custom chat bots for facebook messenger.
The user can login to the system and create a bot with different interactions and finally publish the bot to facebook.

There are a couple of companies that are doing this including Chatfuel. In their system, the user is requested for the pages authentication and they directly publish the bot to your page.

Can someone advise me, How to publish a Chatbot into the Facebook page using only API ?

Thanks.

Comment: They are not “publishing” the app dynamically, they are just subscribing an existing, already approved app to different pages. And how you do that, is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: In your example, you want to have your clients setup a facebook bot, and then add it to their facebook page, correct? You would like to automate user giving your fb app access to their page, and adding their chatbot?

Comment: @JonChurch Exacly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CBroe Can you send me a link to the documentation you said? I did a search and I couldn't find it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/setup#subscribe_app

Comment: Anyone struggling with this? See my question and the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46883836/facebook-graph-api-subscribed-apps-edge-only-works-with-pages-i-own